Cloudfront omits CORS header in preflight request only when Authorization header is included
We have a Cloudfront distribution in front of a HTTP API Gateway.
Cloudfront:

Caching disabled
AllViewerExceptHostHeader
Response Header policy, custom
Adds Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <list>, Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *, Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *

When a preflight request contains the access-control-request-headers with authorization as a value, the response headers omits any CORS headers, but without authorization, it works. Any ideas?
I was expecting the CORS headers to be defined in the response, because our Response Header policy adds them.

authorization isn't listed as an allowed request-header name in your CORS configuration; be aware that this name is special insofar as it's not covered by the wildcard (*). The behaviour you observe isn't surprising to me: many CORS middleware (for better or worse) omit all CORS response headers when preflight fails.

Thank you @jub0bs - these are very valuable links to learn from! I wasn't aware of the non-wildcard headers
